# cakePHP random message in validation

Tags: cakephp

I'm a cakephp newbie - so excuse if this comes across as naive...

Basically, what I am trying to do generate a random message in the validation. Currently my code is

```
                class Post extends AppModel {
                    var $name = 'Post';

                    var $validate = array(
                        'title' => array(
                            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                            'message' => randomResponse()
                        ),
                        'body' => array(
                            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
                        )
                    );

                    function randomResponse() {

                        switch($this->myRandomMessageNumber)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                    echo 'Are we playing charades? If so, you know I can\'t see you';
                                    break;
                            case 2: 
                                    echo 'In english?';
                                    break;
                            case 3:
                                    echo '(signs back)';
                                    break;
                            case 4:
                                    echo 'Am I conversing with a mute?';
                                    break;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Obviously this throws an error by saying that there is an unexpected This is using the blog tutorial that they provide in the documentation. So how can I go about generating this random message?

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cake/app/Model/Post.php on line 11

Comment: Yeah, I did a few tests and it seems that `'message' =>` does not support/accept passing of functions or variables. You might need to entertain another solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute functions in class property declarations in PHP.

In the long run I would say look into a custom validation rule which sets the message, however you could also achieve the same effect easier by assigning the message in the `__construct()`:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->validate['title']['message'] = $this->randomResponse();

    parent::__construct();
}
```

*Note the side effect of this is that this logic will run every time you use the model, even if no validation is occurring, you could write a [custom validation rule](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules) if you wanted to be uber efficient, but the logic here is so simple it's probably not worth it.